# Error: d3.v4.min.js:3 Error: <rect> attribute width: Expected length, "NaN"

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js

I've seen this question a few times and it usually gets resolved by fixing a typo, but I don't think I've got any typos as I only encounter errors when I load data as a csv. Script has no problems loading the same data as json.

```js
d3.csv("mydata.csv", function(data) {

            var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", 500)
                .attr("height", 500)

            canvas.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("width", function(d) {
                    return d.age * 10;
                })
                .attr("height", 46)
                .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                    return i * 50;
                })
                .attr("fill", "blue");

            canvas.selectAll("text")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("text")
                .attr("fill", "white")
                .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                    return i * 50 + 24;
                })
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                })




        })
```

And here are my data files:

JSON:

```js
[
  {"name": "George", "age": 50},
  {"name": "Carla", "age": 29},
  {"name": "Bobby", "age": 18}
]
```

CSV:

```html
"name", "age"
"george", 50
"carla", 29
"bobby", 18
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces in your CSV:

```
"name","age"
"george",50
"carla",29
"bobby",18
```

`d3.csv` is based on RFC 4180, which says:

> Spaces are considered part of a field and should not be ignored.

Working plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/e1Xtz9L8NnUz8FYPRT5G?p=preview